# How to find the actual working directory?

Tags: linux, shell, symbolic-link

When I try to find the current working directory at a linux command prompt (using "pwd"), it will show the directory with symbolic links included. For example, if I make a symbolic link and use it to visit that directory:

```
ln -s /mnt/backup /home/biotech/backup
cd /home/biotech/backup
pwd
```

This will show "/home/biotech/backup" instead of "/mnt/backup". This happens on both Ubuntu and Cygwin.

What command can I use to see the latter, the "real" directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

perheps:

```
pwd -P
```

from help:

"-P : The pathname printed will not contain symbolic links. "

Comment: Freudian slip there?

Comment: @Dan C - right. but it's fixed now ;-] [ hopefully ]

Comment: Haha. I saw it before the edit and was a bit confused.

Answer (score 5):

```
/bin/pwd
```

It doesn't know where you've been or how you got there, so it works it out from first principles.

Comment: Which environment does this work in? For me on OSX, "which pwd" = /bin/pwd, so calling it directly makes no difference. You need the -P flag.

Comment: Anything sane - which apparently does not include Mac OS X.  I've just tried it, and to my complete and utter horror, your observation is correct.  I hate being nannied like that.  It is completely obnoxious.  Somehow, `/bin/pwd` is being told how you did your `cd` (on MacOS X).  That is so infuriating I can hardly type coherently.  Pusillanimous!  Butchery of civilized system.  Grrrrrrr!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  (The exact same test on a Linux worked as stated.  Linux is sane.  And I mainly use MacOS X; I don't get this infuriated with it easily.)

Comment: what's insane about a command behaving consistently regardless of where it's located?

Comment: It means I have to unlearn close to 30 years of sane behaviour and start mapping it to handle a system that deviates unnecessarily from the path of the old ones (like me).  I've no particular problem with the shell knowing how I got to a specific directory, though that sometimes annoys me to.  I have major problems with a command like `/bin/pwd` telling me how it got to the directory; it should work out where it is in the directory hierarchy.  Basically, I've now got to know how to find out the real path on MacOS X differently from everywhere else.  Which is an utter pain for portability.

Comment: And, just for the record, it is MacOS X (maybe BSD) vs 'the rest'; HP-UX, AIX, Solaris and Linux all behave as documented here.  And if I had to guess, so will plain BSD; I'd lay odds it is a Mac-only 'feature' (full pejorative intent completely intended!).

Comment: don't have an OSX system here, but perhaps it helps if you call it like `PWD= /bin/pwd` (with the space, i. e. unset PWD environment variable )?

Comment: Interestingly, that (setting PWD empty, or unsetting it altogether) does work on Mac OS X, as does setting PWD to an invalid value.  It is still frustrating to have to use a different command on Mac OS X to find the real path for the current directory compared with every other Unix-like system.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem for the general case (i.e. not just current directory), use:

```
readlink -f PATH
```

Comment: In the specific case `readlink -f .` would work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

From the shell.

```
pwd -P
```

From userland.

```
/bin/pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a more portable (POSIX-conformant) `pwd -P` command we could use the regular built-in shell `command`:

```
# cf. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06

command -p pwd -P
#builtin command -p pwd -P  
#alias pwd=echo; PATH="$(command -p getconf PATH)" 'pwd' -P
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows7, I use cmd with numerous NTFS hardlinks to folders, cygwin, bash and perl are in my path, but pwd -P doesn't work as suggested above. This script walks up the tree and derefs links to realdir:

```
CHN=$(cygpath -wam .)
echo $CHN
while true ;do
  OLD=$DIR
  DIR=$(cygpath -wam .) 
  if [[ ( -n "$OLD" ) && !( $OLD =~ $DIR* )]] ;then
    SYM=$DIR/${OLD##*/}
    CHN=$(echo $CHN | perl -lpe "s,$OLD,$SYM,")
    echo $CHN
  fi
  case $DIR in [A-Z]:/ | [A-Z]:/cyg* ) break ;; esac # TOPLEVEL
  cd $DIR/..
done
```